# Swift - difference between class level instantiation and method level instantiation

Tags: swift, instance-variables

What is the difference between the following usages? Is there a difference?

```
class B { }

// usage 1
class A {
    var b: B = B();
}

// usage 2
class A {
   var b: B!

   init() {
      self.b = B()
   }
}
```

Edit:
Some of the answers point out that in usage 2 the value does not need to be an optional since it gets a value in the initializer.

Comment: Did you intend `b` to be an optional in usage 2 but not in usage 1?

Comment: FWIW, I've only dabbled in Swift and don't know the answer, but I know it [makes a distinction](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) between "default" values and values assigned in initializers. I suspect that there are subtleties which come into play in an inheritance hierarchy when you look at the order of superclass/subclass initializers. For instance, [Java & C# can call apparently equivalent initialization code in opposite orders](https://chrononaut.org/2008/02/18/java-vs-c-more-fun-with-initializers/).

Comment: I did, but I see now that it did not need to be an optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instantiation is done in the declarative order of the assignation statements. But class level statements (*stored properties*) are done before method level statements:

```
// in this example, the order will be C, D, B, A
class MyClass {
    init() {
        b = B()
        a = A()
    }

    var a: A
    var b: B
    var c: C = C()
    var d: D = D()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the extra `!` in usage 2 is not something you meant, **no there is absolutely no difference** between

```
// usage 1
class A {
    var b: B = B();
}
```

and

```
// usage 2
class A {
   var b: B

   init() {
      self.b = B()
   }
}
```

It's exactly the same.

Comment: Hmm.  I did mean to include the implicitly unwrapped optional, but I now see that I didn't need it.  What would happen if I have an inheritance hierarchy with init() methods, but I also instantiate a variable as in usage 1?  Do the variables initialized in init() get their values before the class level instantiation or after?

Comment: As long as all your variables are initialised by the end of init, no there is no need to make them optional if you don't intend to store nil in them.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there's a huge difference between these two.  In usage 2, `b` is an [implicitly unwrapped optional](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID334).  When you do:

```
let a = A()
```

then `a.b` will be set in both cases, but in usage 2, somebody can then do:

```
a.b = nil
```

and then you'll get an error if you try to use it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a difference between initialization at the declaration site vs. initialization in `init()`, though, just a difference in the property type declaration. (I'd almost go so far as to say it's a typo on the OP's part.)

Comment: David: That's true.  The title of the question and the sample code were about different issues, so I assumed the sample code was the intent of the question, and the title was simply a mistaken description.  I figured it's easier to accidentally use the wrong name for something, than to write 10 lines of code about something you aren't curious about.  :-)